# Excel Web Query Does not refresh

Tags: excel-web-query, excel-external-data

Is there a way to get Excel 2007+ to refresh a web query automatically?  Scenario : I create a spreadsheet. Select Data/From Web. Type in the address of a web service that I know returns a valid response, select the returned xml and the data appears in Excel. However, when selecting the data just imported, clicking on Data/Connections/Properties and ticking 'Refresh Every 1 Minutes', the spreadsheet does not refresh every minute as it should - it does not refresh at all. However, the data can be refreshed by manually right clicking and selecting refresh.  This is not the case for data that is imported from a database using a DSN to connect, it only happens for data from the web.